# Change types in a given scala function

Tags: scala

I have a function

`f : Point2D => Point2D = ???`

I want to convert it to a function of tuples :

`(Double,Double) => (Double,Double)`

I know how to map `Point2D` to `Tuple2` :

```
implicit def pointToTuple(p : Point2D) = (p.x,p.y)
```

but I have no idea how to map **the function itself** :

```
def convertFunction(f : Point2D => Point2D) : (Double,Double) => (Double,Double) = {
    ???
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need `tupleToPoint`, not just `pointToTuple`.

Now, provided you have that, you can just do:

```
  def convertFunction(f: Point2D => Point2D) = 
    tupleToPoint andThen f andThen pointToTuple
```

Comment: actually it only worked if I do `tupleToPoint _ andThen f andThen pointToTuple _` because I have methods, not functions for the conversion